# How to set max-width property for twitter bootstrap popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a popover while hovering over a span

```
$(".ico-sign").setPopover({       
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: $("#divInfo").html()   
});
```

How can I set `max-width` property for this popover?

I have tried this, but doesn't help

```
.popover {
   max-width: 450px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, try to understand html/css and how some js scripts (as popover in bootstrap which is tooltip extension) works.
*(I've occured same problem so here's my solution/s…)*

### in three steps how tooltip works:

**I. bs/tooltip make some calculations on how big your tooltip content is**

```
Tooltip.prototype.getCalculatedOffset = function (placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight) {
return placement == 'bottom' ? { top: pos.top + pos.height,   left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2  } :
       placement == 'top'    ? { top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2  } :
       placement == 'left'   ? { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth } :
    /* placement == 'right' */ { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width   }
}
```

**II. bs/tooltip add some html containers near your trigger element (actually after it)**

**III. according to sizes it get in step one, bs/tooltip places your content absolutely in container from step two**

in addition there is css mentioned before which add some parameters on how this should works and of course looks, i mean especially *max-width* property

```
.popover {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1010;
     display: none;
     max-width: 276px;
     padding: 1px;
     text-align: left;
     white-space: normal;
     background-color: #fff;
     background-clip: padding-box;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
     border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
             box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

as you can see it's nothing more than placing absolute element near trigger element.

**Problem is:** that tooltip is placing tip relatively to the trigger element, but will be positioned relatively to containing, parent item…

### problem conclusion

**In conclusion: while parent item (to trigger) is *width: 100px*, your *max-width: 200px* (on .popover) *is not going to work***

### Solution/s:

**there are at least two solutions:**

1. take your item to upper level in your tree where is more space
2. remove position:relative from parent item
3. use *min-width* on .popover to force min-width value (width also might work)
4. try to extend plugin with some calculation ? (i know - this one's hardcore…)

**post scriptum**
i'm not 100% sure this is how it works and this it the problem cause i had no time to check exactly how bs/tooltip calculate position, but i'm pretty sure that this is positioned relatively to parent and this generates problems (like mine…)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I assume that you are using twitter bootstrap popover

You can do this by using following css;

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  max-width: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

I have prepared for working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/47/). Change `max-width` in css in order to test